# Ajax POST 404 Error With asmx

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am attempting to create a webmethod that I can call/POST to from javascript code, but I obtain the following error in console whenever the test() function is called:

"POST http://localhost:53093/TestMethods.asmx/HelloWorld 404 (Not Found)"

I have checked multiple questions similar to mine, but none of the solutions seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

*TestMethods.asmx.cs*

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://testdomain.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class TestMethods : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod()]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

*Javascript* (game.js)

```
function test()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "TestMethods.asmx/HelloWorld",
        type: 'POST',
        data: "{}",
        dataType: 'json',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

[File Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2mFA.png)

Comment: may be you need to add (../) to url depending on your files structure  url: "../TestMethods.asmx/HelloWorld",

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added an image of my file structure in the original post.

Comment: Sorry Kevin .. anyway I will voteup maybe someone else can help ..good luck man

Comment: When you open **TestMethods.asmx/HelloWorld** in your browser, do you get a 404?